# Maven build for machine learning - how do I get it working?

Tags: maven, machine-learning, pom.xml

I'm trying to compile and run some basic Java code in this repository:
https://github.com/jasebell/mlbookexamples

As an example, inside the Java folder, chapter2.BritneyDilemma.

I'm trying to do this with maven (as there's a pom.xml) but I feel that there's a few things holding me back. I don't know much about Maven; my background is C and cmake. At first glance, I can see why people hate Maven. The pom.xml for the project doesn't seem fully configured / appears quite non-standard:

- It only pulls down some dependencies, for example BritneyDilemma requires classifier4J but this isn't mentioned in the pom.xml.
- When I do any of the simple commands mvn install/compile etc, the output into target is basically nothing (it's an almost empty jar).

I've tried various approaches such as:

- Modifying the pom.xml to add in the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) and running a `mvn clean compile package`. At most I managed to get a jar that packaged the pom.xml dependencies, but still couldn't compile BritneyDilemma due to not having classifier4j (this isn't mentioned in the pom.xml so I'm unsure how maven is supposed to know it's a requirement/where to pull it from).
- Moving away from maven, downloading classifer4j and compiling via the command line. Run time error and a bit of sleuthing pointed out I was missing some [classifier4j dependency](http://sourceforge.net/p/classifier4j/mailman/classifier4j-devel/?viewmonth=200411), I assume this was because I moved away from maven and this would otherwise have been taken care of by some recursive building.

Here is a stock build attempt, making no modifications/taking the pom.xml as is:

```
~/projects/mlbookexamples/java (master) $ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mlbook
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/projects/mlbookexamples/java/src/main/resources
Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone//javax/batch/javax.batch-api/1.0/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
34K downloaded  (javax.batch-api-1.0.jar)
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alex/projects/mlbookexamples/java/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/alex/projects/mlbookexamples/java/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/alex/projects/mlbookexamples/java/target/mlbookexamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/alex/projects/mlbookexamples/java/target/mlbookexamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/alex/.m2/repository/com/datasentiment/mlbook/mlbookexamples/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mlbookexamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 04 08:38:56 NZDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/249M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/projects/mlbookexamples/java/target (master) $ java -jar mlbookexamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in mlbookexamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm running arch linux.

Comment: I dont know how to aquire it on Linux but you need Maven installed - in Windows you would add it to the Path variable to get the 'mvn' programm associated with Maven and then run 'mvn clean install' in the folder where the pom.xml file remains - Maven will inform you about any issues with the pom.xml

Comment: I think you will be able to handle the Linux Part -> http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi as soon as the 'mvn' command is recognized you can build the example with 'mvn clean install' from within the folder where the pom.xml file is located

Comment: I've already got maven installed, a 'mvn clean install' won't work as there are multiple main instances (roughly one for each chapter or so). A mvn install did download half the internet into ~/.m2 , I'm not sure how this got me ahead, as inside the target folder there is still a [basically] empty jar file. If you look at the pom.xml from the project you'll see it only lists a few repositories, so I'm not sure what its full purpose is: https://github.com/jasebell/mlbookexamples/blob/master/java/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile Chapter 2 it appears there's no requirement to grab the dependencies listed in the pom.xml.

You can simply compile BritneyDilemma from the chapter2 folder (remembering to include the Classifier4J dependency downloaded from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/classifier4j/files/ , this can be kept in the chapter2 folder).

```
~/projects/mlbookexamples/java/src/chapter2 (master) $ javac -cp Classifier4J-0.6.jar BritneyDilemma.java
```

You can then go to the src folder and run the class, again with a reference to the classifier4j jar inside the chapter2 folder.

```
~/projects/mlbookexamples/java/src (master) $ java -classpath .:chapter2/Classifier4J-0.6.jar chapter2.BritneyDilemma 
brittany spears = 0.7071067811865475
brittney spears = 0.7071067811865475
britany spears = 0.7071067811865475
britny spears = 0.7071067811865475
briteny spears = 0.7071067811865475
britteny spears = 0.7071067811865475
briney spears = 0.7071067811865475
brittny spears = 0.7071067811865475
brintey spears = 0.7071067811865475
britanny spears = 0.7071067811865475
britiny spears = 0.7071067811865475
britnet spears = 0.7071067811865475
britiney spears = 0.7071067811865475
christina aguilera = 0.0
britney spears = 0.9999999999999998
```

You will likely already have the required logging library, but it can be grabbed through a package manager as libcommons-logging-java.

Alternatively it is much easier to use eclipse in general. Simply create a new Java project but change the working directory from the default to the java directory inside the repository. Create a new folder 'lib' here and put in the classifier4j jar. In eclipse, right click on classifier4j and 'add to build path'. You can now simply click BritneyDilemma or any other source (adding dependencies to lib and adding to build path when necessary), and run as required.

Happy machine learning.